# RViz gets Moveit setup assistant's poses wrong

Tags: ros, pose, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have created a Moveit config package using the moveit_setup_assistant, containing several poses for my 6dof arm. However, when executing these poses using:

```
roslaunch simple6dofarm_config demo.launch rviz_tutorial:=true
```

The poses are wrong, as can be seen on these two comparisons for example:
[image: Reference pose in Moveit assistant]
vs
[image: Reference pose in RViz]
And
[image: Hip left pose in Moveit assistant]
vs
[image: Hip left pose in RViz]

What's going on ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342402/rviz-gets-moveit-setup-assistant%27s-poses-wrong/) by [argargreg](https://answers.ros.org/users/51154/argargreg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-23**:
And please attach your screenshots to the question directly. I've given you sufficient karma for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a chance this could be a locale issue. Note how in the MSA, decimals are separated by a `.` (ie: dot). But in RViz, it's `,` (ie: comma). In your terminal, it's dots again.

I don't know whether this is the cause, but it might be worth checking.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [argargreg](https://answers.ros.org/users/51154/argargreg/) on 2020-01-23**:
Thanks for your answer - and for enabling me to upload the pictures. That's a great idea, however wouldn't the elbow position be 1.77 rad instead of 1 (1560 modulo pi) ? Also, in a python shell float("0,6") generates an error while float("0.6") does not :/ (but if I'm missing something, how to change RViz's locale?)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-24**:
I'm not sure what you mean with the modulo comment: if locale is incorrectly configured, floating nrs will just get truncated (at best). There is no (intelligent) rounding.

> how to change RViz's locale?

You could `export LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8` in a terminal and then start RViz / your launch file from that same terminal. But as I wrote: I'm not sure this is a locale issue. I just noticed the different decimal separators.

**Comment by [argargreg](https://answers.ros.org/users/51154/argargreg/) on 2020-01-27**:
Eagle eye! That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help, add that comment to an answer, I'll accept it gladly :)